# Migrate Web Application to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a Web Application that also have a SQL Data Base and need to migrate to Azure

How to i do this ? Please help me and appreciate if any one could provide me a step by step process.

I tried with azure SQL Server but it is very slow.

Comment: Based on your application's use cases - the compute tier and specs need to be correctly picked. You need to identify why it is slow - check if the bottleneck is CPU or memory or I/O ? Refer to `official Azure migration` guides, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/migration/resources/#popular-resources

Comment: Dear Anand,Thank you for your reply

Comment: this document will help you--https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/migrate/azure-best-practices/contoso-migration-refactor-web-app-sql#migration-goals